# .htaccess 301 forward regex sytax

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, forward

need a code block.

look
my site www.mysite.com ok.. and my new site www.newsite.com
my site searh url : http://www.mysite.com/search.php?key=apple+pie+2+box+59+cent

need a htacces 301 forward code for only forward include apple keyword.

ex : www.mysite.com/search.php?key=apple+pie+2+box+59+cent => www.newsite.com/search.php?key=apple+pie+2+box+59+cent (key include apple ok forw true)

ex : www.mysite.com/search.php?key=banana+and+apple+paste => www.newsite.com/search.php?key=banana+and+apple+paste (key include apple ok forw true)

ex : www.mysite.com/search.php?key=kivi+and+black+berry+juice+cent => www.mysite.com/search.php?key=--NO FORVARD return current site--- (key NOT include apple. no forward false.)

ex : www.mysite.com/search.php?key=one+piece+apple => www.newsite.com/search.php?key=one+piece+apple (key include apple. yes forward true.)

need regxp code..

exam:
RewriteRule ^"only included apple keyword"/(.+)$ www.newsite.com/search.php?key=$1 [L,R=301]

thx for all helpers. 
sorry my english is bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} apple
RewriteRule ^search\.php$ http://www.newsite.com/search.php [QSA,L,R=301]
```